# What does diff --staged compare against staged file to in git?

Tags: git

I understand that git diff compares a staged file and modified but not staged file.

But what files does git diff --staged(or --cached) compare?

A staged file and a committed file?

What are the differences between git diff and git diff --staged?

I am a bit confused.

Thanks in advance.

http://progit.org/book/ch2-2.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a handy graphic

[image: handy graphic]

I talk about it in more detail [here](http://365git.tumblr.com/post/474079664/whats-the-difference-part-1).

Comment: To clarify, `HEAD` means the currently-checked-out commit. (And the OP was right - it's comparing staged contents with committed contents.)

Comment: Does index mean the staged area?

Comment: Yes, the Index is the staging area, and the working tree is the state of tracked files.